# Как получить список всех участников группы?

Tags: vkontakte-api

Для примера взял группу id123377669, численностью 11293 человек, попробовал составить запрос, но в ответ получаю массив ровно на 293 человека... Что я делаю не так? Спасибо!

```
var members = API.groups.getMembers({"group_id":"123377669","count":"1000","offset":"0"});
members = members + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id":"123377669","count":"1000","offset":"1000"});
members = members + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id":"123377669","count":"1000","offset":"2000"});
members = members + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id":"123377669","count":"1000","offset":"3000"});
members = members + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id":"123377669","count":"1000","offset":"4000"});
members = members + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id":"123377669","count":"1000","offset":"5000"});
members = members + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id":"123377669","count":"1000","offset":"6000"});
members = members + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id":"123377669","count":"1000","offset":"7000"});
members = members + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id":"123377669","count":"1000","offset":"8000"});
members = members + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id":"123377669","count":"1000","offset":"9000"});
members = members + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id":"123377669","count":"1000","offset":"10000"});
members = members + API.groups.getMembers({"group_id":"123377669","count":"1000","offset":"11000"});
return members;
```

запрос отправляю черех curl

```
function GetVK($url, $params) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$Group = json_decode(GetVK('https://api.vk.com/method/execute', array(
    'code' => $code,
    'access_token' => $System['access_token'],
    'v' => $System['api_ver']
)), true);
```

$code - это запрос, который в начале топика

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй исправить каждую строку code вот так

```
API.groups.getMembers({"group_id":"123377669","count":"1000","offset":"1000","v":"5.27"}).items;
```

Comment: помогло просто добавить .items
спасибо!

Comment: @Dimastik86, у них бывают с версиями связаны баги потому предпочитаю проставлять старые проверенные в бою